# How can I run an expensive process on SelectionChanged but not when scrolling quickly. (Delay event handler)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having to run what can be a fairly slow task every time the SelectionChanged event of a DataGrid is fired.

The problem I have is that I need to keep the application responsive and if the user is scrolling very quickly using the arrow keys then I don't want to execute the task for every item. Only the item they stop on. (I hope this is making sense!)

I have setup a very basic example to demonstrate, that displays a list of words in a DataGrid and then when you scroll through them it adds them to a ListView.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts;
private bool loading;
private async void dgData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (loading)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        return;
    }

    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    loading = true;
    var x = dgData.SelectedItem.ToString();

    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); //Wait a second to see if scrolling quickly...
        await ExpensiveProcess(x);
    });

    loading = false;
}

private async Task ExpensiveProcess(string text)
{
    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        loading = false;
        return;
    }

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //Expensive process will be done here...
    });

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        lvwItems.Items.Add(text);
    });
    loading = false;
}
```

This appears to work in the fact that if arrow down quickly it misses items, but when I stop on one and want it to run it doesn't work?

Where am I going wrong? Is this even the best approach? Any advice is greatly appreciated and happy to provide further information. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I found a a video on YouTube that suggested doing this which is working as I'd expect so for now I am going for this, but leaving the question open for now for any feedback.

Create a timer which will run the expensive process and set the interval to something low but not too slow so the key presses.

```
var myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
myTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
myTimer.Tick += MyTimer_Tick
```

On the tick event of the timer run the long running process.

```
private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = dgData.SelectedItem.ToString();
    Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); //Needs to be removed
        await ExpensiveProcess(x);
    });
}
```

Then in regular SelectionChanged event simply Stop and Start timer. Also don't forget to Stop the timer at the end of the long process.

Comment: Start a timer in the event handler and then check whether the item is still selected when the timer elapses. If it is, you call the long-running method with a cancellationtoken that you cancel if another selection occurs.

Comment: @mm8 Thank you, I will try adding the CancellationToken to the timer. Are you able to provide an example in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start a timer in the `SelectionChanged` event handler and then check whether the item is still selected when the timer elapses.

If it is, you call the long-running method with a `CancellationToken` that you cancel if another selection occurs.

The following sample code should give you the idea:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts = null;
...
dataGrid.SelectionChanged += async(ss, ee) =>
{
    //cancel any previous long running operation
    if (_cts != null)
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        _cts.Dispose();
    }
    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    //store a local copy the unique id or something of the currently selected item
    var id = (dataGrid.SelectedItem as TestItem).Id;
    //wait a second and a half before doing anything...
    await Task.Delay(1500);
    //if no other item has been selected since {id} was selected, call the long running operation
    if (_cts != null && id == (dataGrid.SelectedItem as TestItem).Id)
    {
        try
        {
            await LongRunningOperation(id, _cts.Token);
        }
        finally
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
            _cts.Dispose();
            _cts = null;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the approach I ended up implementing and it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the event, if you use a data-binding on the `SelectedItem` property you can achieve this easily using the `Delay` property. `Delay` will wait n milliseconds before processing a change.

```
<DataGrid ...
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Delay=1000}">
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. How will this stop the others firing though? Won't this just delay the setting of the property?

Comment: Essentially the binding won't process a change, until it has been n milliseconds since the last change. So scrolling with the arrows quickly won't fire a change until the user stops of n milliseconds. A delay of 1000 is a bit much. I would reduce it to 500.

Comment: Ah okay. So then how I would go about raising the method in the code behind? As I don't think it is possible for me to move this to the ViewModel unfortunately :( I will give it a go though, thank you :)